# Differences between 'div .class', '.class' and '.class div'

Tags: css

I have a div like : `<div class='class'>`

I notice that div.class handles this style, while .class div does not. Moreover, .class handles the style as well.

Why is that ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> I notice that `div.class` handles this style, while `.class div does` not.

`div.class` looks for a `div` with the `class` class present.

`.class div` looks for a `div` that is a descendent of an element with the `class` class.

Your element is a `div` *with* the `class` class, hence the selector does not select it.

> Moreover, `.class` handles the style as well.

`.class` will select any element with that class, including any `div` elements.

Comment: +1 Also read up on selector specificity: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 4):

A space is a descendent selector, i.e. "Matches the right hand side only if one of its **ancestors** matches the left hand side".

[image]

See [the descendant section of Selectutorial](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/document_descendant.htm)

`.class` works because any element that matches the rule "A div that is a member of the class 'class'" will also match the rule "A member of the class 'class'", it is just less specific.

Answer (score 3):

`div.class` refers to all divs with the class 'class.' `.class div`, on the other hand, refers to all divs that are children of the element with the class 'class.' `.class` refers to all elements with the class 'class.'

Answer (score 2):

1. div.class: Select a div with a class attribute
   of value "class". Can be written as div[class="class"]
2. .class div: Select
       a div which is a decendant of any
       element which has a class attribute of value
       "class". Can be written as [class="class"] div
3. .class: Select any element which has a
   class attribute of value "class". Can be written as [class="class"]

Although the dot, fullstop, period, . , is used instead.